# Add another java source directory to gradle script

Tags: java, gradle

I hava an example java project package

package com.example.testing;

with such file tree

```
app
|
  src->com->example->testing->Main.java
```

and a gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src'
        }
    }


}

sourceSets.main.output.classesDir = file("classes")
mainClassName = 'com.example.testing.Main'

defaultTasks 'compileJava', 'run'
```

Now I want to add some module to this project and my folders will be something like this

```
app
|
  src1->com->example->testing->Main.java

  src2->com->another_example->another_testing->Library.java
```

How do I add new source code to gradle script?

Comment: Why don't you respect the standard gradle/Maven conventions? Everything would work fine automatically, without needing to configure all the paths.

Comment: I for instance would like to have a separate directory for generated sources.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I agree with @JB Nizet about respecting standard conventions. If you still insist on being an Anarchist though:

You already have `src` declared in your sourceset, why not add `src1` and `src2` as well? You can add them to the same sourceset, or define a sourceset per module if you want.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src'
            srcDirs 'src1'
            srcDirs 'src2'
        }
    }
 }
```

To reference files outside the project, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190324/in-gradle-how-to-use-sources-from-relative-path-outside-of-project).

Comment: While I agree with wanting to use standard conventions, this one tip was useful when dealing with "generated" sources, which wind up wherever the generator tool feel like tossing them... so, thanks!

Answer (score 26):

The question is about "Adding"; the question of the text is describing a more concrete scenario. If one just wants to add an existing directory, this is the way to *add*:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += ['src/gen/java']
```

An example full `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.12.1'
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += ['src/gen/java']
```

[JavaPoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet#javapoet) s a Java API for generating `.java` source files. It is just used as example library for the `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 17):

I have a slightly different approach with a Gradle 4.6:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir 'build/swagger-code-dummy/src/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see, I had to specify the directories with the "/main/java" subdirectories as well, otherwise gradle/intellij was not setting the right path.

Maybe this helps someone else too :)

Comment: This is also helpful if your project involves multiple languages, such as Python or Bash, and you need those directories to be treated like source roots also.

Comment: When do you do this? Before or after generating the code? And do you need to add the dependencies?

Answer (score 13):

A slightly different solution:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['build/jasper', 'src/main/java']
```

Comment: I am using VSCode and gradle and adding a similar line in build.gradle solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but might help someone:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs "${buildDir}/generated/openapi/src/main/java", generatedSourceDir
    }
}
```

After gradle build, I am able to import classes from both the build directory and the 'generated' src directory:

[image]