# How to access files from some folder inside an android application module?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, resources

Consider a gradle project that contains 3 sub-projects:

```
root
    |
    |> androidModule
    |> coreModule
    |> desktopModule
```

I decided to centralize some project files (e.g. fonts, binaries) inside the `coreModule` but I can't load then inside the `androidModule`. This was chosen once those files are being used either in `androidModule`, either in `desktopModule`, as well.

I tried a lot of ways of declaring custom `sourceSets` in the `androidModule/build.gradle.kts` but I still can't access the files. One attempt I tried so far:

```kotlin
android {
  sourceSets["main"].resources {
    srcDirs(arrayOf("coreModule/example/targeted/folder", "other/path", "etc"))
  }
}
```

Also, my attempt to load the file inside some android activity code is:

```kotlin
val resultStream = assets.open("file-from-the-custom-folder") //no such file or directory here
println(resultStream)
```

Then, how to deal with that multiple resources directories in android gradle module?

I was trying to avoid centralize the files to be in the androidModule because I think they can be accessed by the other modules easly if living in that module, by the way I also really think that the files should be inside the core module, making this place more consistent about locations/pathing. What the best way to handle this?

Comment: Are these files in the assets folder?  If not, they won't be accessible as assets.

Comment: The files is in a arbitrary directory. In my example of the question, inside a neighbor module. Is necessary the folder have the name "assets"? This example something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62693361/4563960. Other related example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68246046/4563960

Comment: The files in your directory on your PC have no bearing in the format of the APK.  None of those files are directly copied over.  The kotlin and java files are compiled and combined into a couple of .dex files.  The resources are similarly combined and compiled.  Anything else in the src directory would just be dropped-  except for the files in the assets directory, which will be put into the special assets section of the APK.  Which is the only data that AssetManager (like you use above) can access.

Comment: So yes, if you want to put a file into your apk, it must be in an assets directory.  The srcSet stuff is a way to include other Java/Kotlin code, not files.  Which is why it's called sourceSets-  it's sets of source code.  Not of random files.

Comment: Hi Gabe, I just droped an answer detailing how I achieved that. For now, using my custom directory to hold general files seems to work on both android and jvm modules. Feel free to point me something to improve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the unfortunate response "not possible to use arbitrary directory" as holder for common files to be accesed by android and/or other kotlin modules I started to study a bit about Gradle Source Sets possibilities.

After that I found that we make a module look and use some folder as resources/assets (general files, not source code) by doing this in its `build.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
android {
  //...

  // get access to configs about the "main" source set
  sourceSets.getByName("main") {
    // creates an empty directories paths holder
    val allNeededDirectories = mutableListOf<String>()

    // adds all current existing defined dirs of the gradle defaults
    allNeededDirectories.addAll(assets.srcDirs.map { it.toString() })
    
    // adds a custom and user-created directory
    allNeededDirectories += project
      .layout
      .projectDirectory
      .dir("../my_awsome_custom_directory")
      .toString()
    
    // defines the dirs list above to be the main [assets] srcDirs
    assets.setSrcDirs(allNeededDirectories)
  }
}
```

Note to the `../` prefix to access `my_awsome_custom_directory`, which is in a previous level from the current gradle module/sub project.

Also, note to the `android` block. This means that external general files (e.g.: fonts, binaries) are treated as "assets", while "resources" are pre-indexed files, through the `R` class. For this reason, inside android activity to access a file named "`my_file.test`" from the `my_awsome_custom_directory` we can do:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  val resultStreamOfFile = assets.open("my_file.test")
  println(resultStreamOfFile.readText())
}
```

In addition, when setting the custom `my_awsome_custom_directory` to be acceced by other module different of android, e.g., pure Jvm, is very similar:

```kotlin
kotlin {
  //...

  // get access to configs about the "main" source set
  sourceSets.getByName("main") {
    // creates an empty directories paths holder
    val allNeededDirectories = mutableListOf<String>()

    // adds all current existing defined dirs of the gradle defaults
    allNeededDirectories.addAll(resources.srcDirs.map { it.toString() })
    
    // adds a custom and user-created directory
    allNeededDirectories += project
      .layout
      .projectDirectory
      .dir("../my_awsome_custom_directory")
      .toString()
    
    // defines the dirs list above to be the main [resources] srcDirs
    resources.setSrcDirs(allNeededDirectories)
  }
}
```

The difference is that we need to define the paths to `resources` instead of `assets`. This is due to the `assets` is only provided by the `android` plugin, when the `kotlin("jvm")` provides `resources`.

By the end, all experiments above I made in a application of mine and is working well. However, if some point of my explanations are messy or if this could not work well in a specific scnenario, please, feel free to correct then!