# How to access generated classes in build folder of Gradle project from src folder in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I generated classes from wsdl file in build folder of the Gradle project in Intellij. But I have some compilation errors when I try to create an object from generated classes. Because it is obvious that I cannot give a reference in src folder for classes outside of src folder. How can I do this?

**EDIT-1:** My project has a root module that has 2 inner modules is placed on src folder of root module. "gen" class has generated classes and I want to use them in "main" module in src folder. But, how?
[image]

**EDIT-2:** About Peter's recommendation, I am sharing the print screen. I cannot reach outside of src folder!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to the project structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S or File->Project Structure), select `module` and select the module of your concern.

Then click the `sources` tab and turn your generation folder into a source code folder. There is a row of buttons: `Mark as:`[image: Mark folder as source folder]

I would expect that your build folder is already marked as excluded but you can have a source folder inside an excluded folder.

Comment: Thank u for your contribution, but still having a problem. Hierarchy of my project modules are told in edit part of the question. I've just added it. Please, check it.

Comment: please check two photos on my question

Comment: Another solution is to add the source folder to your gradle setup. see
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077844/add-another-java-source-directory-to-gradle-script]