# Can IntelliJ import non-standard source directories from Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am converting over to using IntelliJ (version 2019.1).   The multi-project directory structure used has the standard `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` for each project, but additionally has some non-standard ones such as: `src/testsupport/java`.

Gradlew (using the internal/recommended gradlew packaged within IntelliJ) is used to import the projects.  The Gradle build files include both:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
```

**Edited to improve clarity**

Every project imports fine.  Interproject references work to the standard directories.  However, when I am in Project B, but need access to `src/generated/java` or `src/testsupport/java` from Project A, those are not imported (`import` statements that compile fine from the gradle command line show up as unresolvable within IntelliJ).  Is there a configuration change or something needed to make these take effect?

Currently, I have:

```
subprojects {
    idea {
        module {
            testSourceDirs += project.sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs
            testSourceDirs += project.sourceSets.testsupport.java.srcDirs
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IDEA supports multiple source and test directories if you set them in Gradle correctly. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077844/add-another-java-source-directory-to-gradle-script — this topic may be useful.

Comment: That isn't helping exactly.  Edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: @JoeG post your code. Post your Gradle and IntelliJ versions. Those are the most important parts, and they are missing from your question.

Comment: @JBNizet added.  Am using the gradlew contained within IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

You need help Gradle out by creating a source set for the custom sources your projects define. So from your question, something like:

(using Kotlin DSL)

```
allprojects {
    apply {
        plugin("idea")
        plugin("java-library")
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    configure<SourceSetContainer> {
        create("generated") {
            compileClasspath += project.the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"].output
            runtimeClasspath += project.the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"].output
        }
        create("testsupport") {
            compileClasspath += project.the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"].output
            runtimeClasspath += project.the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"].output
        }
    }

    val api by configurations
    val testImplementation by configurations
    val testRuntimeOnly by configurations

    dependencies {
        api(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.5.1"))
        testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
        testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    }

    val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

The above will give you:

[image]

So now you want to use `projectA` in `projectB`, so `projectB`'s Gradle file would include a dependency on `projectA`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(":projectA")
}
```

This should hopefully get you started. Keep in mind, the examples given above use the [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) which you should be able to convert back to Groovy.

References:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#source_sets
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests